# Get method throwing Request.Path exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to ASP.NET Web API and I'm trying to make a simple GET Request that will return a person object.

```
public string Get(string first, string last)
{
    Person person = new Person(first, last);

    return person.ToString();     
}
```

This is just supposed to return my person object as a string.

Now I'm trying to navigate to this using the following URL-

http://localhost:35431/api/values/first&last

But it only throws Request.Path exception.

Basically my question is how can I navigate to this through a URL? I know this is pretty basic but I just need a little guidance to get started.

Thanks!

Comment: try using http://localhost:35431/api/values/first/last

Comment: @rashfmnb I just tried it. It gave me an error 404.

Comment: update your routes

Comment: The url should contain a query with a first parameter and a last parameter like this: http://localhost:35431/api/values?first=John&last=Doe

Comment: @rashfmnb Thanks so much! Understanding how routing worked was confusing me.

Comment: @venerik Thanks! Once the way you added the query string it pretty much worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like that :

```
http://localhost:35431/api/values?first=SomeValue1&last=SomeValue2
```

Also you use AttributeRouting:

```
[Route("api/values/{first}/{last}")]
public string Get(string first, string last)
```

and then:

```
http://localhost:35431/api/values/SomeValue1/SomeValue2
```